# Users Login with Multiple permission levels via SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I want user login with Multiple permission levels, My SQL has Perm_type column 
I want when Perm_type is 1 show Administrator, Perm_type is 2 show Staff

I don't know how to add code to check  Perm_type

[image: SQL]

My Code is

```
  public Login_form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        /*initialize connection*/
        con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=demo;user=demouser;Pwd=demopassword;SslMode=none");

    }
    private void Login_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Log In Button
    {
        string user = id_txt.Text;
        string pass = Pwd_txt.Text;
        cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM demo_login where id='" + id_txt.Text + "' AND password='" + Pwd_txt.Text + "'";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {

                Administrator new_Form = new Administrator();
            new_Form.Show();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login please check username and password");
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [any documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader)?

Comment: Little Bobby Tables? http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Never glue bits of string together to make a SQL query - use SQL  Parameters always.  Never ever store passwords as plain text - salt and hash them.